# not included the authorities what I need in google oauth scope

Tags: youtube, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

hello I'm a novice in google api.
I already inserted youtube api authorities in this page https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent.
and then when I check google oauth page, it doesn't show any authorities what I need.
when I click any account, then just go to main page.
[image]

and I checked the issue in the intelliJ debug console.
here is only three authorities.
how can I solve this issue?
thank you in advance

[image]
[image]

here is the code below.

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomOAuth2UserService implements OAuth2UserService<OAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2User> {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final HttpSession httpSession;

    @Override
    public OAuth2User loadUser(OAuth2UserRequest userRequest) throws OAuth2AuthenticationException {
        OAuth2UserService<OAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2User> delegate = new DefaultOAuth2UserService();
        OAuth2User oAuth2User = delegate.loadUser(userRequest);

        String registrationId = userRequest.getClientRegistration().getRegistrationId();
        String userNameAttributeName = userRequest.getClientRegistration()
                .getProviderDetails()
                .getUserInfoEndpoint()
                .getUserNameAttributeName();

        OAuthAttribute attributes = OAuthAttribute.of(registrationId, userNameAttributeName, oAuth2User.getAttributes());
        User user = saveOrUpdate(attributes);
        httpSession.setAttribute("user", new SessionUser(user));

        return new DefaultOAuth2User(
                Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRoleKey())),
                attributes.getAttributes(),
                attributes.getNameAttributeKey());
    }

    private User saveOrUpdate(OAuthAttribute attribute) {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(attribute.getEmail())
                .map(it -> it.update(attribute.getName(), attribute.getPicture()))
                .orElse(attribute.toEntity());

        return userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final CustomOAuth2UserService customOAuth2UserService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .headers().frameOptions().disable()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/css/**", "/images/**", "/js/**", "/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/**").hasRole(RoleType.USER.name())
                .antMatchers("/welcome").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                .userInfoEndpoint()
                .userService(customOAuth2UserService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
                .requestMatchers(PathRequest.toStaticResources().atCommonLocations());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your authorization code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youtube Data api is channel based not not user based. You need to pick which channel you want to grant access the application access to.  After that you will see the consent screen where it tells you what scopes of access the application is requesting.

Comment: I would like to use the subscription api with mine true so I need to the user infomation

Comment: then you need to request the profile scope and go though the people api.  Which subscription api are you referring to?

Comment: yeh according to the document I need some youtube authorities like `auth/youtube.readonly`. what I called the api is like this `https://content-youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?mine=true&order=relevance&part=snippet&forChannelId=xxxx&key=xxxxyyyzz`
`channelId` and `key` are variables

Comment: you need to add the readonly scope i can see from your image you have not added that.  To be clear you want to access the subscriptions method within the Youtube data api.    Methods are not their own apis.

Comment: do I have to add the authorities other page?? I already added them in https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent page

Comment: you need to add it to your code please post your code.

Comment: ahh I forgot my code I have added it. could you check it, please?

Comment: ohhh I knew it!! I should add extra scope in application.properties. when I add them, it works. but I'm curious why do I have to add some authorities to oauth consent page and application file?

Comment: Consent screen page is more for when you apply for verification of your app the team wants to know what scopes you are planning on using.  by adding them there you are declaring what your using.